# Rectangular connected component extraction in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

There are multiple rectangular areas in the 2d-numpy array. All the rectangular areas have value 1, other areas are zero. I want to extract a minimum number of rectangular connected components from the numpy array. These connected components can touch each other in any direction.

I tried extracting connected components using `label` function from `scipy.ndimage.measurements` but it assigns the same label to rectangles which touch each other.

I also tried, morphological opening but I do not want to lose the original shape of the rectangle.

The image shows the expected output for a better understanding of the problem.[image: Expected output]

Is there a better way to extract a minimum number of perfectly rectangular regions?

Comment: This is an underconstrained problem. For example, regions 2+3 can be split into rectangles in at least two ways (2 + 3; or left half of 2 + right half of 2 and left half of 3 + right half of 3). Even if you specify you want squares, there will be some configurations that are ambiguous. If you say "the fewest possible regions", you could turn it into an optimization problem.

Comment: Yes, I want fewest possible regions. I will edit the question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thanks actually you solved my problem.

Comment: could you please update the post on the solution?:)

Comment: I did not understand what you are asking me to do?